# Sharing RegistrationController for two devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two devise models, Individual and Group. I'm trying to share similar behavior for Registrations/Confirmations (send users to a page that informs them that an email has been sent, or send them to the edit page after confirmation, etc.)

My issue is that this works for Individuals, only. It has yet to work for Groups.

config/outes.rb:

```
 devise_for :individuals, :controllers => {:confirmations => "Confirmation", :registrations => "Registrations"}

 devise_for :groups, :controllers => {:confirmations => "Confirmation", :registrations => "Registrations"}
```

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(item)
    "/post_sign_up?email=#{item.email}"
  end
end
```

app/controllers/confirmation_controller.rb:

```
class ConfirmationController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def after_confirmation_path_for(name, resource)
    case resource.class
      when Individual then edit_individual_path resource
      when Group then edit_group_path resource
      else super name, resource
    end
  end
end
```

The above code works for individuals, only. Can't figure out why though.

Answer (score 0):

I was focused so heavily on the provided lines in routes.rb, I failed to notice another "devise_for :groups" at the top of the file. Apparently devise will override previous values in this case. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

for scale & no errors - better to devide.

admin_registration_controller.rb:

```
class AdminRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

user_registration_controller.rb:

```
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

routes:

```
devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: 'admin_registrations' }
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'user_registrations' }
```